# Why doesn't my alert alert or my log log?

Tags: jquery, html, logging, alert, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a large json file that, if it has any unexpected entries in various elements, fails. So, rather than copy in a few "recods" at a time to see where it breaks (it works, but is very time-consuming and tedious), I've tried to get it to let me know how far it's getting by alerting me as to its progress:

```
$.getJSON('Content/pulitzers.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, dataPoint) {
        if (IsYear(dataPoint.category)) {
            htmlBuilder += '<div class=\"yearBanner\">' + dataPoint.category + '</div>';
            alert(dataPoint.category);
        } else {
```

...and, when that didn't work (better idea, anyway), with a log message:

```
. . .
            if (IsYear(dataPoint.category)) {
                htmlBuilder += '<div class=\"yearBanner\">' + dataPoint.category + '</div>';
                console.log(dataPoint.category);
. . .
```

...However, they only work when all that is fed in is good, anyway. IOW, I'll see "2013" down to "2009" if all that is good, but when I add it "records" down to 2005, in which there is a problem somewhere, it simply fails without a peep or a whimper.

How can get it to give me more feedback?

Alternatively, is there a "json validation" site that will unleash robots on the json file to czech it for being well-formed?

Comment: You can paste your JSON into [**jsonlint**](http://jsonlint.com/) to check if it's valid. Using a method on the serverside that converts your data to valid JSON would avoid such issues for the most part. Also there is a progress event for ajax, but you won't get any progress in the success handler the way you're doing it, and probably not any other way that is easily achiveable either.

Comment: `to czech it` - you made my day, thank you.

Comment: @Adaneo - make the jsonlint link an answer, and I'll mark it - that solved my travails.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: I've spelled "check" as "czech" since 2006, when I went to Prague and environs - best beer in the world, on tap, and cheap.

Comment: @adeneo He spelled your name wrong - come back and reap the sweet, sweet karma!

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - thanks for the heads up. ClayShannon - posted the comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste your JSON into [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to check if it's valid.

Using a method on the serverside that converts your data to valid JSON would avoid such issues for the most part.

Also there is a [progress](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.progress/) event for ajax, but you won't get any progress in the success handler the way you're doing it, and probably not any other way that is easily achiveable either.